# Why do python projects have the following structure?

Tags: python, python-packaging

I am working on creating my own installable python package using `setup.py`. While going over different repositories, I find the following structure -

```
abc-def
|-abc_def
|-setup.py
```

Here, `setup.py` has the function `setup` with the following contents -

```py
setup(
    name="abc_def",
)
```

My question is, does the parent directory need to share its name with the child directory, just swapping the `-` for a `_`. Especially since it seems that python doesn't accept the `-` symbol. For instance, if I use import `abc-def` anywhere in the code, I get the following error -

```
>>> import abc-def
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    import abc-def
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the root `abc-def` directory is the name of the project's source directory tree. This name does not matter at all for Python or packaging. This is a convention to keep the name of the project's source directory tree the same as the name of the distribution package.

The name `abc-def` written as `name` in `setup.py` is the name of the [distribution package](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/glossary/#term-Distribution-Package). And `abc_def` (directory `abc-def/abc_def`) is the name of the top-level [import package](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/glossary/#term-Import-Package). So you `pip install abc-def`, but you import `abc_def`. Both names can be completely different (for example "[beautiful soup 4](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/)"), but the convention in the Python community is that both names should be the same name modulo the normalizations (dashes `-` for distribution package names vs. underscores `_` for import package names).

The import package name has to be a valid Python identifier, so dashes `-` are not allowed.

The normalization rules for distribution package names are specified here in this document: [*Names and normalization*](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/name-normalization/). So a distribution package named `abc-def`, can also be installed like any of the following and still the same package would be installed:

- `abc-def`
- `abc_def`
- `abc.def`
- `AbC_-._-dEf`

The way you write the distribution package name in `setup.py` is the way it will appear on *PyPI*. See these examples:

- [`Sphinx`](https://pypi.org/project/Sphinx/) has a capital `S`
- [`zope.interface`](https://pypi.org/project/zope.interface/) has a dot `.`

Answer (score 0):

1. python projects often have this structure, because this was what was recommended with [setuptools](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/quickstart.html)
2. It is not compulsory to keep same names cf. [here](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html)

> Although setuptools allows developers to create a very complex mapping
> between directory names and package names, it is better to keep it
> simple and reflect the desired package hierarchy in the directory
> structure, preserving the same names.

3. new projects are advised to use `pyproject.toml` instead of `setup.py`